# Given a list of points of (x,y) in 2D plane, count number of rectangles with edges not necessarily parallel to x,y-axis

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

Given a list of points of `(int x,int y)` in 2D **integer** grid plane, count number of rectangles with edges not necessarily parallel to x,y-axis

For example, given a list of `[(0,0), (0,2), (1,1), (-1, 1)]` return `1`.

`[(-1,0), (0, 1), (2,3), (4,1),(2,-1),(1,-2)]` return `3`.

```java
class Point {
    public int x;
    public int y;
}

class Solution {
    public int countRectangles(List<Point> points) {

    }
}
```

Right now, I can only come up with an `O(n^3)` algorithm, that is for every three points `p1, p2, p3` we check whether `p1-p2` orthogonal to `p2-p3` by `O(1)`, use math formula to get `p4` by `O(1)` and check whether `p4` in HashSet of points by `O(1)`.

Is there any more efficient algorithm like `O(n^2)`?

Comment: @AloisChristen Calculating angles will involve floating point math. Floating point math isn't sufficient accurate for this task. Calculations shall be kept as integer calculations.

Comment: @user3386109 Given two opposite points, the other two may have many possibilities for a rectangle. If we consider the other two as an integer, it converts to the problem that from a center, draw a circle with a fixed radius, and it can exactly pass which integer grid points.

Comment: @SupportUkraine true, didn't think of that. Maybe there's a possibility with rounding (as we just need to have compatible lines together, but we can rule out false positive later) but even then I don't think it's guaranteed to work.

Comment: @SupportUkraine We can classify line by angle, not with floating point math but with an  integer vector (with minimal length). This involve some math to compute the vectors, but classify the lines accuratly

Comment: Can we consider center-radius 2D voting space? (but I don't know about efficiency)
Given two opposite points, we can obtain the circle''s center and radius. So I think that, If we collect the data from all point-pair, we can find rectangles from duplications.

Comment: I doubt that you can do better than O(n^3). Perhaps consider asking https://math.stackexchange.com/ But I'm not sure whether the question fits their rules...

Comment: Here's a way to do it O(n^2)? General idea is to calculate all potential diagonal distances. If the length of two diagonals is same AND they meet at the same point(in the middle, i.e. midpoint of two diagonals is identical), we have a rectangle.

Comment: Calculate distances between all pairs of (p1,p2) and save a hashmap of distances(better to save without the square root to avoid floating point errors) to array of (p1,p2)(this would be `O(n^2)`). Now, to count the no. of rectangles, for each key in the distance hashmap create another hashmap with key being the mid point of diagonal(p1,p2). We should be able to get no. of rectangles having diagonals of that distance by traversing the values of this new hashmap.(this would be `O(n^2)`). The worst case would be when all points are concentric, and distance for all (pi, pj) pairs would be same.